# get phone number in android

Tags: android

I got all contact name in spinner. How do I get phone number according to select name? Please help me.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        int x=0;
        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner);

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                People.NAME,
                People.NUMBER,People._ID
             };
        ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor=cr.query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection,null, null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String name[]=new String[cursor.getCount()];
            do
            {

                 name[x]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
                //name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
                 //phoneNumber=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));
                 //id=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
                x++;

                //Toast.makeText(this,"name:"+name+"number:"+phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call getPhoneNumber method with a name,You will get phoneNumber

```
Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
                String phoneNumber=getPhoneNumber(intentContact,name.getText().toString());




protected String getPhoneNumber(Intent intent,String Name)
        {
           String name;
           Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
           while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
           {           
               String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
               name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
               if (!taskAssignedToName.equals(name)) continue; 
               String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

               if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                   hasPhone = "true";
               else hasPhone="false";
               if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
               {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                {
                  return phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
                phones.close();

               }


           }
           return "";
        }
```